# Error while executing Hive Command

Tags: hadoop

I'm trying to execute following command on Hive.

```
CREATE TABLE tblHbase(key int, a int, b int,c bigint)
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,f:a,f:b,f:c")
TBLPROPERTIES("hbase.table.name"="tblHbase");
```

Error is:
Error in metadata: MetaException(message:org.apache.hadoop.hbase.MasterNotRunningException: Retried 10 times.
How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: The HMaster is not running, there could be tons of reasons for it. Without much information, it would be difficult to figure it out.

Comment: http://projects.spring.io/spring-hadoop/#quick-start

Comment: https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/r1.2.1/mapred_tutorial.html#DistributedCache

Comment: http://codingwiththomas.blogspot.in/2011/05/k-means-clustering-with-mapreduce.html

Comment: https://spectrallyclustered.wordpress.com/category/hadoop/

Comment: http://www.nuxeo.com/blog/mining-wikipedia-with-hadoop-and-pig-for-natural-language-processing/--- pig

Comment: @PraveenSripati look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26380517/pig-hangs-up-when-integrating-with-hbase) question. Can you plz answer how to solve this?

Comment: This is due to my master node service automatically starts & stops.

Comment: http://www.folkstalk.com/2011/11/string-functions-in-hive.html

Comment: https://coderwall.com/p/imxf6g/running-wordcount-on-hadoop-using-r-script  ---- R wordcont

Comment: https://gist.github.com/airawat

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]Hi Kumar, This is due to my master node service automatically starts & stops. I resolve this error by cheking which service is running on that port. Then I Restart the hadoop services. Then next time all services running properly.